# delete data below 10% of column average

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

If I have a table with 2 columns, and I want to delete the data from the table where the data from column 1 is not in top 90% of column 2 average value

```
column 1     |   column 2
-------------+----------------
100000.00    |  1000000.00
150000.00    |  1500000.00
180000.00    |  1800000.00
```

I already got the avg value with code

```
SELECT AVG([column2*0.1) 
FROM #t
```

Average = 143333.333333

but I struggle to find a way to use the value as a where condition

Comment: I simply do not know what you mean by "data from column 1 is not in top 90% of column 2 average value".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery or cte:

```
with cte as (select column1, avg(column2) over() avg_column2 from mytable)
delete from cte where column1 < avg_column2 * 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, maybe that can help you out:

```
DECLARE @column2Avg decimal;

SELECT @column2Avg = AVG([column2]) 
FROM #t

DELETE FROM #t
WHERE column1 < @column2Avg*0.1
```

Sure, you should wrap it up with a Transaction clause.